# How to use the method makeDifference in the console?

Tags: pyqgis, differences

I would like to do a "difference" between 2 features in PyQGIS.

I don't understand how to use the method `makeDifference()` as shown on the documentation [here](http://qgis.org/api/2.18/classQgsGeometry.html#a48fb03c594930a2e5536b79bd14d9b77).

It says the parameter to pass the function is:

```
QgsGeometry makeDifference (const QgsGeometry &other)
```

I have tried the following code but don't see any change in the feature.

```
layers = iface.legendInterface().layers()
layer = layers[0]

# I select the feature that will erase all the others
features = layer.selectedFeatures()

#Get the other features
layer.invertSelection()
inverse = layer.selectedFeatures()

#Erase all the other features with my selected feature
for f in inverse:
    try:
        layer.dataProvider().changeGeometryValues({f.id(): 
        features[0].geometry().makeDifference(f.geometry())})
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: The link you posted refers to the upcoming QGIS 3.0. Which QGIS version are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need to perform a simple difference operation between to features, the [difference()](http://qgis.org/api/2.18/classQgsGeometry.html#aa980f7083f14c5f5b61a22cf2377d5c1) method should be enough.

Assuming to start from two features stored in a list:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
feats_list = []
for feat in layer.getFeatures():
   feats_list.append(feat)

print feats_list
# 'feats_list' is something like:
# [<qgis._core.QgsFeature object at 0x17658A30>, <qgis._core.QgsFeature object at 0x17658A80>]
```

you preliminarily need to get the geometry of each feature:

```
geoms_list = [item.geometry() for item in feats_list]

print geoms_list
# 'geoms_list' is something like:
# [<qgis._core.QgsGeometry object at 0x17658B70>, <qgis._core.QgsGeometry object at 0x176589E0>]
```

and the evaluating the difference between them:

```
geom1 = geoms_list[0]
geom2 = geoms_list[1]

diff = geom1.difference(geom2)
```

The `diff` variable will be still a geometry object. You can then use it for creating a new feature and add it to a layer.

Comment: @Blue I'm glad it was helpful!